# Separate tailwind configs in brunch

Tags: brunch, tailwind-css

I want to have two separate CSS files being outputted by Brunch, essentially this:

```
stylesheets: {
  joinTo: {
    "css/app.css": "css/user_portal/*.css",
    "css/admin/app.css": "css/admin/*.css",
  },
},
```

But I want both of them to use different tailwind config files. Currently I only have what the docs says:

```
postcss: {
  processors: [
    require('tailwindcss')('./tailwind.js'),
  ]
}
```

But this of course makes both css-files use them same tailwind config.

Is there a solution for this with brunch?